# Which things to do in AutoCAD and which in 3ds Max?

Tags: 3dsmax

I learned 3ds Max two months ago. I am not perfect in it, but I used it to make a model of a house. I am interested in house architectures. I used to model everything in Max.

I have just started to learn AutoCAD and it has been two weeks. I realized that AutoCAD is very accurate in modelling floor plans, doors, windows, etc.

The teacher told me that every thing from a chair to a pen to a bed, etc., can be modelled in AutoCAD.

Now I am confused as to which is the right way to model house interiors, AutoCAD or Max.

I want to know at what point should I finish things in Autocad and then move to Max?

Comment: Why not use both? Model the house in AutoCAD because it's easy/fun/preferable for you, export it to something Max understands and then use Max to texture it and add other details. I had a friend that would use Hammer(the Half-Life 1/2 map editor) for the base model, then export it to Milkshape for texturing and details. Worked very well until he got the hang of doing everything in Milkshape. It's a natural transition.

Comment: Just on the editing ... I'm in Australia, and we use realise = realize. It's listed in the Macquarie concise dictionary as an equality just like that. I understand the American spelling uses a z, and is a more natural form. I'm just trying to bring our nations together <heart>. Of course if user1094163 isn't a virtualized jacker, but rather a real person living in the states, then he has no excuse :)

Comment: my Main concern is about interiors. Should they be done in maxor cad

Comment: I presume it depends on what you plan to do with the models. AutoCAD, as the name implies, is a CAD package, so you get the precision tools and extras that help actually in manufacturing the model in one form or another. 3dsmax is more general purpose and at it's roots, AFAIK, is more targeted towards CG and animation (stuff that mainly stays on a screen). You've got 2 tools that help you work in 3D, but the final output would dictate the tools you would use for to model, in my opinion. Since autodesk owns both packages, file exchange is easy so you can always export to 3dsmax to render later.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on what it's for and what your employee is telling you to do (if you get to that stage). If this is just for yourself, don't bother with Autocad, just use Max, it's so much more fun. Max and Maya are great tools for 3d visualization, I've seen some wicked home interiors made with these packages. You can model everything in Max for visualization, but if you need technical specs then Autocad might be the way to go.

Listen to what anyone says about Autocad, because I don't know it much, I've studied Max and to a lesser degree Maya. So an autocad user might have some things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've used AutoCAD. However, I believe AutoCAD is designed more towards professional architects that plan on drafting blueprints along with visuals whereas Max is mostly visuals with the ability to get really creative at design time and designed for artists.

The target audience of AutoCAD and it's functionality may have changed since my experience while working as a land surveyor.

Answer (score 0):

simply when the need for high prisition AutoCAD better for drafting 3DMax better.
I working with CAD and Max you can drow in CAD and Modifying in MAX and rendering because MAX is Faster in rendering